# A proof of the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence

Here is an exercise which is meant to prove the existence of the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition of a complex matrix.

Let $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, and let $\mu_{A} = \prod\limits_{k = 1}^{r} (X - \lambda_{k})^{n_{k}}$ be its minimal polynomial (with $\lambda_{k}$ distinct complex numbers, $n_{k} > 0$).

Show that $\{ P \in \mathbb{C}[X]/ P(A)$ is nilpotent $\} = \{ Q(X)(X - \lambda_{1}) ... (X - \lambda_{r}) / Q \in \mathbb{C}[X] \}$, and use it to prove that there exists a polynomial $P$ such that $P(A)$ is nilpotent and $A - P(A)$ is diagonalizable.

I have no issues with the first statement, but I cannot manage to find a polynomial $P$ satisfying what we are looking for ...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have an ideal and $\Bbb C[x]$ is a PID. Hence...

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to say ... Yes, $\{ Q(X)(X - \lambda_{1}) ... (X - \lambda_{r}) / Q \in \mathbb{C}[X] \}$ is an ideal, and obviously it is a principal one. But I do not see where this leads ...

Comment: So take $P$ to be a generator, and try to show it works.

Comment: So I should try to prove that $A - (A - \lambda_{1} I_{n}) ... (A - \lambda_{r} I_{n})$ is diagonalizable ? Well thank you, I will try.

Comment: Here I am again ... I tried to prove what was stated above, but I failed ... Could you please give me an explanation of how to do/start it ? Thank you